How to add the drawing I need on another material
I'm relatively new to using Blender. I'm creating a model for my game in blender and I want to add the drawing on my box like it was drawn manually, but I don't know how. I know about vertex paint, but as I know this method requires high-poly model. I guess there is a better way to solve my problem. I want to make my box low-poly as much as it possible with my current skills. If there is no other option but use vertex paint, please let me know about it.  First picture is my box. Second picture is an example of  what I want to do.

Here is an example. As I said, I want this to look like it was drawn manually on the wooden box.


Paint your drawing on a transparent PNG image, mix it with your current setup with a Mix Shader, use the Alpha as Factor, plug the Normal if you want to have 3D relief on the drawing as well:

